# cannot cross-compile busybox for arm

Tags: compiling, embedded, arm, busybox, cross-compilation

I've configured my busybox in menuconfig and made it as a static binary (no shared libs) + forced no MMU build.

I'm using the prebuilt arm cross compiler and when I enter the below command, it gave me error while building the source code.

```
sudo make -j8 ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-
```

it gave me this log:

```
  LINK    busybox_unstripped
Static linking against glibc, can't use --gc-sections
Trying libraries: m resolv
Failed: -Wl,--start-group  -lm -lresolv  -Wl,--end-group
Output of:
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wunused -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-function -Wunused-value -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wno-format-security -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wold-style-definition -fno-builtin-strlen -finline-limit=0 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-guess-branch-probability -funsigned-char -static-libgcc -falign-functions=1 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-labels=1 -falign-loops=1 -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-builtin-printf -Os -static -o busybox_unstripped -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--sort-section,alignment -Wl,--start-group applets/built-in.o archival/lib.a archival/libarchive/lib.a console-tools/lib.a coreutils/lib.a coreutils/libcoreutils/lib.a debianutils/lib.a klibc-utils/lib.a e2fsprogs/lib.a editors/lib.a findutils/lib.a init/lib.a libbb/lib.a libpwdgrp/lib.a loginutils/lib.a mailutils/lib.a miscutils/lib.a modutils/lib.a networking/lib.a networking/libiproute/lib.a networking/udhcp/lib.a printutils/lib.a procps/lib.a runit/lib.a selinux/lib.a shell/lib.a sysklogd/lib.a util-linux/lib.a util-linux/volume_id/lib.a archival/built-in.o archival/libarchive/built-in.o console-tools/built-in.o coreutils/built-in.o coreutils/libcoreutils/built-in.o debianutils/built-in.o klibc-utils/built-in.o e2fsprogs/built-in.o editors/built-in.o findutils/built-in.o init/built-in.o libbb/built-in.o libpwdgrp/built-in.o loginutils/built-in.o mailutils/built-in.o miscutils/built-in.o modutils/built-in.o networking/built-in.o networking/libiproute/built-in.o networking/udhcp/built-in.o printutils/built-in.o procps/built-in.o runit/built-in.o selinux/built-in.o shell/built-in.o sysklogd/built-in.o util-linux/built-in.o util-linux/volume_id/built-in.o -Wl,--end-group -Wl,--start-group -lm -lresolv -Wl,--end-group
==========
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: libbb/lib.a(inet_common.o): in function `INET6_resolve':
inet_common.c:(.text.INET6_resolve+0x50): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: coreutils/lib.a(mktemp.o): in function `mktemp_main':
mktemp.c:(.text.mktemp_main+0x9c): warning: the use of `mktemp' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp' or `mkdtemp'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: networking/lib.a(ipcalc.o): in function `ipcalc_main':
ipcalc.c:(.text.ipcalc_main+0x238): warning: Using 'gethostbyaddr' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: libbb/lib.a(inet_common.o): in function `INET_resolve':
inet_common.c:(.text.INET_resolve+0x50): warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: networking/lib.a(inetd.o): in function `reread_config_file':
inetd.c:(.text.reread_config_file+0x3b0): warning: Using 'getservbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: networking/lib.a(netstat.o): in function `ip_port_str':
netstat.c:(.text.ip_port_str+0x50): warning: Using 'getservbyport' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: util-linux/lib.a(rdate.o): in function `rdate_main':
rdate.c:(.text.rdate_main+0xec): undefined reference to `stime'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: coreutils/lib.a(date.o): in function `date_main':
date.c:(.text.date_main+0x248): undefined reference to `stime'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Note: if build needs additional libraries, put them in CONFIG_EXTRA_LDLIBS.
Example: CONFIG_EXTRA_LDLIBS="pthread dl tirpc audit pam"
make: *** [Makefile:718: busybox_unstripped] Error 1
```

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=252864 http://mirror.as43289.net/gentoo-portage/sys-apps/busybox/files/busybox-1.31.1-glibc-2.31.patch

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thanks. I'm newbie in open-source programming. how can I apply a patch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Linaro arm toolchain instead of glibc. the default arm gnu compiler on ubuntu is not stable.

https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/arm-linux-gnueabihf/